# How to send and receive UDP multicast data on the same machine?

Tags: network

I cannot seem to receive multicast data I that send with tcpreplay(-edit), on the same Mac. This works fine on Linux using the loopback device.

On Mac, not even tcpdump sees the multicast data when using the loopback device. tcpdump does however see the multicast data when using interface en6. Still, socat is not able to receive it.

How can I get this to work? I don't care if data flows via loopback or a real network interface.

Btw this works perfectly fine over en6 when sending from another machine, i.e. over physical cable, to interface en6.

I'm on MacOS Sonoma (14.2.1), Apple M2, and the firewall is inactive. See below for information about test procedure and network setup.

```
> sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:51501,ip-add-membership=239.194.23.1:192.168.1.6,fork -


> sudo tcpdump -i en6 -nn 'udp and port 51501'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on en6, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 524288 bytes
11:06:33.275339 IP 10.17.95.53.51501 > 239.194.23.1.51501: UDP, length 79
11:06:33.315256 IP 10.17.95.53.51501 > 239.194.23.1.51501: UDP, length 176
11:06:33.349584 IP 10.17.95.53.51501 > 239.194.23.1.51501: UDP, length 273
11:06:33.388508 IP 10.17.95.53.51501 > 239.194.23.1.51501: UDP, length 370
11:06:33.427230 IP 10.17.95.53.51501 > 239.194.23.1.51501: UDP, length 79
...

> sudo tcpreplay-edit -CM 1 -ien6 za-dump.pcap
Actual: 3490 packets (525503 bytes) sent in 4.20 seconds
Rated: 125026.1 Bps, 1.00 Mbps, 830.33 pps
Flows: 24 flows, 5.71 fps, 3490 unique flow packets, 0 unique non-flow packets
Statistics for network device: en6
        Successful packets:        3489
        Failed packets:            0
        Truncated packets:         0
        Retried packets (ENOBUFS): 0
        Retried packets (EAGAIN):  0


> netstat -ng
Link-layer Multicast Group Memberships
Group                   Link-layer Address      Netif
1:0:5e:42:17:1          <none>                  en6
1:0:5e:0:0:fb           <none>                  en6
1:0:5e:0:0:1            <none>                  en6
...

IPv4 Multicast Group Memberships
Group                   Link-layer Address      Netif
239.194.23.1            1:0:5e:42:17:1          en6
224.0.0.251             1:0:5e:0:0:fb           en6
224.0.0.1               1:0:5e:0:0:1            en6
...

> ifconfig en6
en6: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=404<VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO>
        ether 00:e0:4c:85:78:ab
        inet 192.168.1.6 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect (2500Base-T <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```